# Transform matrix in Raphael.js

Tags: raphael, affinetransform

I'm looking to apply a 2D affine transform matrix to ellipses I have created in Raphael. I understand that the underlying SVG can support this, but does Raphael provide a way to access this?

```
newShape = paper.ellipse(100, 200, 50, 150);
// apply transform here
```

I have tried parsing transform matrices myself, working out rotation, scaling and translation manually and applying in Raphael, but it didn't seem to work and I thought there must be a better way?

Many thanks, 
 Will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beta for Raphael.js 2.0 came out last week--

https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/tree/2.0

There is a new 'transform' method that seems to be just what you're looking for.

Brian

Comment: Thanks for that Brian.
I see the transform method takes a string, with an 'm' for Matrix:

    newShape.transform("m1,2,3,4.567,5,6")

Works great!